# Some clarifications about Hibernate caching mechanism?

Tags: hibernate

I have questions on the statements I found while going through hibernate caching tutorial.

Statement1:-First-level cache always Associates with the Session object. Hibernate uses this cache by default.

**Question1:**- 
As this cache is by default holding all the results from session methods like load,get etc. **Wont it be a major memory issue because of holding  all the objects in seesion ?**

**Question2:**- 
Do we need to enable this cache or its there by default? Can I disable First level cache, if I want? If yes how?

*Below questions are for both first level and  second level cache*

**Question3:-** 
If I get the same object from cache(say I load the  object customer with customerid 1 twice in the same session)both  objects  returned from cache will be having different references from the object lying in cache. **Right?** Because if I update some field in customer object, it should not reflect in cache until and unless save/update method is called.

**Question4:-**
As per my understanding if we try to get the customer object from id 1 second time from this cache, it will return the same old object even if it got updated in between. **How can we ensure if it got updated it reads from database otherwise from cache?** I guess we can use read write cache strategy  with class like **EHCache**

**Question5:- On Query Caching**
I read this statement :-Updates in the queries occur very often. So, for query caching, two cache regions are necessary.

For storing the results.( cache identifier values and results of value type only).
For storing the most recent updates.

I think “Updates in the queries occur very often” mean here we usually change some parameter value like `select * from customer where custid=?` So `id` will be changed for different customer id. So query cache will keep each query (along with parameter ) and results returned by each query. 
**Right? But not sure why do we need two cache region for query caching?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK
***Answer 01:***
Hibernate caches the objects loaded so as to avoid unwanted access to database. The simplest way to avoid a persistance context would be to use a `StatelessSession`. A Stateless Hibernate Session has no dirty checking responsibility and hence goes well with your requirement of not having the first level cache(Persistant Context).

***Answer 02:***

1. You don't have to enable first level cache

***Answer 03***

1. If an object is loaded twice **in the same session** using its identity, Hibernate makes sure that  the same object is returned regardless of whether the second level cache is enabled. Let me clarify that **second level cache DOES NOT cache instances of object**. It maintains a serialized (not exactly) version of the instance.
   The following [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190719063218/https://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html) gives a brief explanation of structure of hibernate second level cache.

*I am sorry but I fail to understand the concept behind "updating customer object and it not being reflected in the cache". I hope the link clarifies your question.*

***Answer 04***

1. Problems of stale data fetched from cache do arise if not configured correctly.
   State data will be fetched if the expiration time on the cache has not occurred. Eviction can be carried out using `Session.evict()` however chances are you might not have a clear idea of what data needs to evicted. Hence **caching should always be the final step in optimizing your access to database.**
   Good level of optimization can be achieved by re-evaluating the associations and fetch-plans on collection relations so as to avoid N+1 selection issues and at the same time avoid.
   **EHCache** provides `read-write` caching stratergies for data which does not get updated
   that conforms to transaction `read committed` protection. That is it avoid [dirty reads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) but cannot help against [repeatable reads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)).

Check out EHCache configuration [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140817211849/http://ehcache.org:80/documentation/user-guide/hibernate)

**Answer 05 : Query Caching**

1. Check Out these links for better understanding of Session Cache and Query Cache
   A. [Session Cache](https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/)
   B. [Second Level Cache](https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/)
   C. [Query Cache](https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/)
2. [Checkout this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190719063218/https://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html) which gives a brief/simpler explanation of structure of query cache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks rictionlesspulley for such a elaborate reply.I have these followup queries. As you said " Let me clarify that second level cache DOES NOT cache instances of object. It maintains a serialized (not exactly) version of the instance"" I did not get what do you mean by serialized version of cahe?  Regarding EH CAche, as you said we can get read committed transaction acroos ression. This is what i need.

Comment: If you go to the second link in the Answer 05, you will see exactly how objects are stored in the second level cache. And I meant serialized version of the * cached object * NOT THE CACHE ITSELF.

Comment: About the read-write cache strategy of EHCache be sure to set appropriate cache expiration time!